# Create Model classes from mongodb collection or JSON in django

Tags: python, json, django, mongodb

Is there a way to create model using data that has already been loaded into mongodb or from a JSON object for a new django application? I know that it can be done manually, but considering the fact the JSON has many keys, it is going to be tedious.

EDIT:

I am using the Yelp dataset. The data is in the form of JSON, which is currently stored in MongoDB.

**Example:**

```
{
   "business_id":"O_X3PGhk3Y5JWVi866qlJg",
   "full_address":"1501 W Bell Rd\nPhoenix, AZ 85023",
   "hours":{
      "Monday":{
         "close":"18:00",
         "open":"11:00"
      },
      "Tuesday":{
         "close":"18:00",
         "open":"11:00"
      },
      "Friday":{
         "close":"18:00",
         "open":"11:00"
      },
      "Wednesday":{
         "close":"18:00",
         "open":"11:00"
      },
      "Thursday":{
         "close":"18:00",
         "open":"11:00"
      },
      "Sunday":{
         "close":"18:00",
         "open":"11:00"
      },
      "Saturday":{
         "close":"18:00",
         "open":"11:00"
      }
   },
   "open":true,
   "categories":[
      "Active Life",
      "Arts & Entertainment",
      "Stadiums & Arenas",
      "Horse Racing"
   ],
   "city":"Phoenix",
   "review_count":29,
   "name":"Turf Paradise Race Course",
   "neighborhoods":[

   ],
   "longitude":-112.0923293,
   "state":"AZ",
   "stars":4.0,
   "latitude":33.638572699999997,
   "attributes":{
      "Take-out":false,
      "Wi-Fi":"free",
      "Good For":{
         "dessert":false,
         "latenight":false,
         "lunch":false,
         "dinner":false,
         "brunch":false,
         "breakfast":false
      },
      "Noise Level":"average",
      "Takes Reservations":true,
      "Has TV":true,
      "Delivery":false,
      "Ambience":{
         "romantic":false,
         "intimate":false,
         "touristy":false,
         "hipster":false,
         "divey":false,
         "classy":false,
         "trendy":false,
         "upscale":false,
         "casual":false
      },
      "Parking":{
         "garage":false,
         "street":false,
         "validated":false,
         "lot":true,
         "valet":true
      },
      "Wheelchair Accessible":true,
      "Outdoor Seating":true,
      "Attire":"casual",
      "Alcohol":"full_bar",
      "Waiter Service":true,
      "Accepts Credit Cards":true,
      "Good for Kids":false,
      "Good For Groups":true,
      "Price Range":2
   },
   "type":"business"
}
```

SO far, I've been querying the data using pymongo, but I would like to use django models. What I'm looking for is a convenient way to generate a model from the already existing data.

Comment: There are a few options available: [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) is one, or google https://www.google.com/search?q=django+mongodb

Comment: mongoengine requires the models to be already present no? Can I create models dynamically using the existing data?

Comment: That is fine but your question is also very unclear. What are you trying to generate from? Something like a twitter API response? Then I would question that you need a model at all. Otherwise add some part (shortened) of the sort of thing you are working with in JSON. And your question then becomes "how to generate code by traversing a data structure"

Comment: Unless you actually have something more to add, then I would suggest looking here: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.DynamicDocument